# ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'XXXModule' was called

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

First I will mention I have done the prerequisit and searched google and S/O for the solution and found this to either be a generic falling over error on unupdated 3rd part modules or the solutions defined don't help. I have followed them still to no avail.

I am getting:

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
>    Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'XXXModule' was called.

I know I'm not permitted to have functions in NgModule declarations but I explicitly list the use of the factory on the provider. Other than that there isn't a function beyond forRoot.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I am trying to register a module in AppModule

**app.module.ts:**

```
import etc... all done 

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    XXXModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
```

**xxx.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService,
    { provide: CookieService, useFactory: cookieServiceFactory }
  ]
})
export class XXXModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: XXXModule,

      providers: [
        { provide: XXXConfig, useFactory: xxxFactory}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I also have the factories in the same file:

```
export function cookieServiceFactory() { return new CookieService(); }

export function xxxFactory(): XXXConfig{
  return {authUrl: `${environment.apiUrl}/api/authorisation`};
}
```

**In a separate file** I define XXXConfig, this is imported fine.

```
export class XXXConfig {
  authUrl: string;
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you solved this? I have encountered the same problem after updating to v9.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. The code was referencing the wrong internal code. As it has been packaged previously the imports were pulling form different locations. Once these had been corrected in a new package it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

A mismatched version of your module may cause this.
I have the same issue with Angular NgxUiLoaderModule.

"Error: Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'NgxUiLoaderModule' was called."

I have Angular 11 so I installed ngx-ui-loader@11.0.0 Solved my issue.
npm i --save ngx-ui-loader@11.0.0